# Using Skia Sharp to create the perfect circle with text in centre

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I want to create a circle with some text in the centre basically the month and the day.

So I have tried form this example.
I am using Xamrain forms so the examples is geared toward winforms by the looks of it, how would i change it to xamrian forms.

https://gist.github.com/xoofx/a9d08a37c43f692e65df80a1888c488b

```
public CircleLabel()
{
        var resizeFactor = 0.5f;
        var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode("input.jpg");
        var toBitmap = new SKBitmap((int)Math.Round(bitmap.Width * resizeFactor), (int)Math.Round(bitmap.Height * resizeFactor), bitmap.ColorType, bitmap.AlphaType);
        var canvas = new SKCanvas(toBitmap);

        // Draw a bitmap rescaled
        canvas.SetMatrix(SKMatrix.MakeScale(resizeFactor, resizeFactor));
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0);
        canvas.ResetMatrix();

        var font = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Arial");
        var brush = new SKPaint
        {
            Typeface = font,
            TextSize = 64.0f,
            IsAntialias = true,
            Color = new SKColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
        };
        canvas.DrawText("Jun!", 0, bitmap.Height * resizeFactor / 2.0f, brush);
        canvas.DrawText("26", 0, bitmap.Height * resizeFactor / 2.0f, brush);

        canvas.Flush();

        var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(toBitmap);
        var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, 90);

        using (var stream = new FileStream("output.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            data.SaveTo(stream);

        }
        imageCircle.Source = "output.jpg";
        data.Dispose();
        image.Dispose();
        canvas.Dispose();
        brush.Dispose();
        font.Dispose();
        toBitmap.Dispose();
        bitmap.Dispose();
}
```

Ideal I am wanting this in a list view but no idea how to achieve that. For now am creating a custom control that I can then consume in a list view.
I am basically wanting to recreate the purple circle you see in synfusions calendar component.

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?  Does it have an error or throw an exception?  Does it not work correctly?

Comment: Its designed for winforms an xamrian forms app is compiled there for how do i send the image to the image control instead of a file @jas

Comment: SkiaSharp is cross platform.  I don't see any code that wouldn't work in Xamarin.  You can use `ImageSource.FromStream()` to create an ImageSource instead of a file

Comment: Thanks @Jason worked a treat just the alignment is a bit off i need the month on the top and the day on the bottom

Comment: you're drawing both strings at the **same exact coordinates**, so you need to adjust your algorithm a bit